# How to run mypy over my test code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, mypy

I've got a project where only the acceptance test code is Python, and I'd like to make sure I've type annotated it properly. Currently the tests are run as follows:

```
python -m unittest discover test
```

Is there some way to integrate `mypy` into that command without too much change? I'd rather not run the tests twice. Do I have to override `unittest.TestLoader` to do this?

Alternatively, `mypy` does support running modules with `-m`/`--module`, but `mypy --module=unittest discover test` fails with

> mypy: error: May only specify one of: module, package, files, or command.

Is there a way to pass module parameters to `mypy`?

Comment: Maybe you could use `pytest` as your test-runner and then add the [`pytest-mypy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-mypy) plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mypy does not run Python code at all.  It is strictly a static analysis program.  So there is no such thing as "run[ning] the tests twice" in this case.  That is, you won't have to wait for your tests to run to get results from mypy.  Just run mypy over the test package or module like you would with non-test code (for simple cases, `mypy test_foo.py`, for more complex cases, see [the mypy documentation](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#specifying-files-and-directories-to-be-checked)).